# Understanding parsing of XML elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML in a file.

```
        <config>
        <appSettings>
                <DEV>
                <INDIR>\\serv1\TEST\INDIR\</INDIR>
                <OUTDIR>\\serv1\TEST\OUTDIR\</OUTDIR>
                <LOGDIR>\\serv1\TEST\LOGDIR\</LOGDIR>
                </DEV>
                <STAGE>
                <INDIR>\\serv1\INDIR\</INDIR>
                <OUTDIR>\\serv1\OUTDIR\</OUTDIR>
                <LOGDIR>\\serv1\LOGDIR\</LOGDIR>
                </STAGE>
                <PROD>
                <INDIR>\\serv2\INDIR\</INDIR>
                <OUTDIR>\\serv2\OUTDIR\</OUTDIR>
                <LOGDIR>\\serv2\LOGDIR\</LOGDIR>
                </PROD>
        </appSettings> 
        <execSettings>
                <DEV>
                <FILTER>*.TXT</FILTER>
                <RETENTION>7</RETENTION> <!-- in days -->
                </DEV>
                <STAGE>
                <FILTER>*.TXT</FILTER>
                <RETENTION>14</RETENTION> <!-- in days -->
                </STAGE>
                <PROD>
                <FILTER>*.TXT</FILTER>
                <RETENTION>60</RETENTION> <!-- in days -->
                </PROD>    
        </execSettings> 
    </config>
```

Using a variable named ‘platform’ holding the string “DEV” or “STAGE” or “PROD”, I want
to get the elements of that platform from the respective part in appSettings and  execSettings
and set them in the following class.

```
        public class config
    {
            public string InDir { get; set; }
            public string OutDir { get; set; }
            public string LogDir { get; set; }
            public string Filter { get; set; }
            public Int32 Retention { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the code attempt. As indicated in comments, my counts are zero for the node
lists. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    string platform = "DEV";
    IEnumerator ienum;
    try
    { 
    xDoc.Load(xmlFile);
    string xPath1 = "appSettings/" + platform;
    string xPath2 = "execSettings/" + platform;

    XmlNodeList appElements = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("xPath1");  //count = 0
    XmlNodeList execElements = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("xPath2"); //count = 0

    config cSet = new config();

    ienum = appElements.GetEnumerator(); //null
    while (ienum.MoveNext())
    {
            XmlNode INDIR = (XmlNode)ienum.Current;
            XmlNode OUTDIR = (XmlNode)ienum.Current;
            XmlNode LOGDIR = (XmlNode)ienum.Current;
            cSet.InDir = INDIR.InnerText;
            cSet.OutDir = OUTDIR.InnerText;
            cSet.LogDir = LOGDIR.InnerText;
    }

    ienum = execElements.GetEnumerator(); //null
    while (ienum.MoveNext())
    {
            XmlNode FILTER = (XmlNode)ienum.Current;
            XmlNode RETENTION = (XmlNode)ienum.Current;
            cSet.Filter = FILTER.InnerText;
            cSet.Retention = RETENTION.InnerText;
    }
```

With the feedback I've received (thanks to all), here is an updated code posting, condensed, but I'm still seeing count = 0 for the XmlNodeList.

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string platform = "DEV";
        try
        { 
                xDoc.Load(xmlFile);
                string xPath1 = "appSettings/" + platform;
                XmlNodeList appElements = xDoc.SelectNodes("xPath1");  //count = 0

                config cSet = new config();
                foreach (XmlNode node in appElements)
                {
                        cSet.InDir = node["./INDIR"].InnerText;
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                ADHOC.func.RecordTo_LogFile("XML||Load_Failure");
                throw (ex);
        }
```

Comment: what C# version is this for? Can you use LINQ?

Comment: usinf VB 2010 framework 4 @BrokenGlass

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with XPath queries so use `SelectNodes` instead.

```
string xPath1 = "//appSettings/" + platform;
string xPath2 = "//execSettings/" + platform;

XmlNodeList appElements = xDoc.SelectNodes(xPath1);
XmlNodeList execElements = xDoc.SelectNodes(xPath2);
```

Also the loops won't properly retrieve your nodes data.

```
foreach (XmlNode appNode in appElements)
{
        XmlNode INDIR = appNode.selectSingleNode("./INDIR");
        XmlNode OUTDIR = appNode.selectSingleNode("./OUTDIR");
        XmlNode LOGDIR = appNode.selectSingleNode("./LOGDIR");
        cSet.InDir = INDIR.InnerText;
        cSet.OutDir = OUTDIR.InnerText;
        cSet.LogDir = LOGDIR.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. ".selectSingleNode" does not resolve. Here is what i have now but i'm still finding count = 0 for the XmlNodeList. 'code' XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
string platform = "DEV";

try
{ 
  xDoc.Load(xmlFile);

  string xPath1 = "appSettings/" + platform;

  XmlNodeList appElements = xDoc.SelectNodes("xPath1");  //count = 0

  foreach (XmlNode node in appElements)
  {
    string INDIR = node["./INDIR"].InnerText;
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ADHOC.func.RecordTo_LogFile("XML||Load_Failure");
  throw (ex);
}
'code'

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - i've posted an update but still having problems. @Avilo

Answer (score 1):

How about you solve the problem in a completely different way: instead if those Prod / Dev nodes use **[XML Transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx)**. They are fully supported by MSBUild and leave your config files much cleaner.

Comment: The code model can't be changed. The code relates to a service.

Comment: @user623688 - By code model you mean your config class? You won't need to change that...

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out the solution for those who are interested...

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string platform = "DEV";            
        try
        { 
                xDoc.Load(xmlFile);
                string xPath1 = "descendant::appSettings/" + platform;

                XmlNodeList appElements = xDoc.SelectNodes(xPath1);  
                config cSet = new config();
                foreach (XmlNode node in appElements)
                {
                        cSet.InDir = node.SelectSingleNode("./INDIR").InnerText;
                        cSet.OutDir = node.SelectSingleNode("./OUTDIR").InnerText;
                        cSet.LogDir = node.SelectSingleNode("./LOGDIR").InnerText;
                }           
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                ADHOC.func.RecordTo_LogFile("XML||Load_Failure");
                throw (ex);
        }
```

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out.  You could also do a node search with "//appSettings/" + platform.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how strongly tied you feel you are to your configuration class above, but I'd strongly suggest moving away from XPath'ing out values. My preference for custom configuration files (unless you are using the .NET Configuration Manager) would be to use XmlSerialization which provides you with a strongly typed object based approach to your problem. In order to meet your above XML file however you'd have to alter your config class, but perhaps not its interface:

This is a rough take based on a notepad copy of what you have supplied:

```
[XmlRoot("config")]
public class Configuration
{
    [XmlElement("appSettings")]
    public AppSettings ApplicationSettings
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlElement("execSettings")]
    public ExecSettings ExecutionSettings
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[XmlRoot("appSettings")] // Not really necessary this xmlroot
public class AppSettings
{
    [XmlElement("DEV")]
    public EnvironmentSetting Development
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlElement("STAGE")]         
    public EnvironmentSetting Staging
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlElement("PROD")]
    public EnvironmentSetting Production
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[XmlRoot("execSettings")] // Not really necessary this xmlroot
public class ExecSettings
{
    [XmlElement("DEV")]
    public ExecutionSetting Development
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlElement("STAGE")]         
    public ExecutionSetting Staging
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlElement("PROD")]
    public ExecutionSetting Production
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class EnvironmentSetting
{
    [XmlElement("INDIR")]
    public string InDirectory
    {
       get;
       set;
    } 

    [XmlElement("OUTDIR")]
    public string OutDirectory
    {
       get;
       set;
    } 

    [XmlElement("LOGDIR")]
    public string LogDirectory
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
}


public class ExecutionSetting
{
    [XmlElement("FILTER")]
    public string Filter 
    {
       get;
       set;
    } 

    [XmlElement("RETENTION")]
    public string Retention
    {
       get;
       set;
    } 
}
```

Having populated such an object you could then either serialize it using the XmlSerializer in the System.Xml.Serialization namespace

```
Configuration config = new Configuration ();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
string resultXml = serializer.Serialize(settings);
```

or vice-versa

Configuration config = (Configuration ) serializer.Deserialize(appConfigText);
   config.AppSettings.Development.InDir = ... e.t.c.

XmlSerializers are great for strongly typed configuration.

Comment: Incidentally, as I read your original question, you may want a more dynamic approach to the above so that you are not limited to just DEV, STAGE and PROD variants, this can be achieved using XMLSerialization still and load objects into an array or dictionary of configurations which could then be searched by key which would represent your 'platform' variable. Let me know if you want more information on that point.